# Links in Revit models not showing in Model Derivative API (Viewer)

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

I'm using a combination of the Postman tutorials available on Autodesk Platform services. I'm using data management to access the signed s3 download url of a revit model in BIM360 through the versions endpoint, then using this to upload a file to a bucket and start a translation job in Model Derivative to show in the Viewer.

When the job is complete, I cannot see the linked structures involved in the revit file and am only getting the information of the model directly saved in it.

The url used is taken from the version:
file['relationships']['storage']['meta']['links']['href'] + "/signeds3download"

Looking at the tutorials for Inventor, those files come with an assembly instruction file (.iam) is there a similar process / file for revit models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a design that's made of multiple files referencing each other that you want to translate for viewing, you have two options:

1. Pack all files into a *.zip file, upload the archive using the Data Management service, and start a Model Derivative service translation with `compressedUrn: true` and `rootFilename` pointing to the master file (see [this tutorial](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/translate-zip-to-stl/) for more details)
2. Upload all files individually, and specify the relationships among them using the [POST references](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/jobs/urn-references-POST/) endpoint (see [this tutorial](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/translate-source-file-containing-xref/task3-translate-source-file/) for more details)

Products such as BIM360 or ACC are already handling this for you, that's why the model displays correctly there.

Btw. if your designs are already in BIM360, there's no need to translate them again, and you can load them directly into your viewer app. For more information, please check out the [Hubs Browser](https://tutorials.autodesk.io/tutorials/hubs-browser/) tutorial.

Comment: Hey Petr, thanks for your answer it actually helped explain some things. Outside of the Hubs Browser, we are looking to load a translated .rvt file from BIM360 into an application-associated bucket. We've got the manifest for the translation in BIM360, is there a way to move the SVF2 file?

Comment: The outputs of Model Derivative translation (whether it's SVF or SVF2 data) is stored and managed by the Model Derivative service itself, so there's no easy way to "move" it anywhere. If you really needed to move the data, you'd have to move the original source file(s), and translate them again.